# Uniform random edge in graph

Tags: java, algorithm

i have a weighted graph that I have stored with a adjecent matrix.
The matrix looks like this:

```
       v1 v2 v3 v4
    v1 0  1  0  2
    v2 1  0  3  0
    v3 0  3  0  0
    v4 2  0  0  0
```

Now I want to select a random at uniform edge.
I already have tried to do it and it seems to work. But the problem is that sometimes it finds the edge (v1,v1) or (v2,v2) or ... . But in my graph this edges never exists.

So how can I select an random at uniform edge without having this problem?

This is my code:

```
int countEdges = matrix.getCountEdges();
Random rand = new Random();
int randomNum = rand.nextInt((2*countEdges));
int x=0,y=0,s=0;
while(s<randomNum) {
    s = s + matrix.getamountOfEdgesOnVertex(x);
    x = x + 1;
}
randomNum = randomNum - (s-(matrix.getamountOfEdgesOnVertex(x)));
s = 0;
while(s<randomNum) {
    s = s + matrix.getWeightOfEdge(x, y);
    y = y + 1;
}
System.out.println("x: "+x+" y: "+y);
```

Comment: That code doesn't seem to relate to the question... you're not even using the random number.

Comment: I think your correction is wrong. It looks like you meant to compare s to randomNum, not rand.

Comment: Sorry. I have corrected my code it but this problem was only here. In my original it is correct and I am still having the problem.

Comment: What is the type of `matrix`? How is it indexed (0-based or 1-based)?

Comment: 0-based. But I already have tried with while(s<randomNum-1). And it is a int[][] matrix.

Comment: Does the edge weight have any influence in the selected edge?

Comment: Yes the selected edge should be selected with the probability proportional to its weight.

Comment: In this example, does getCountEdges return 12?

Comment: No. It returns 6. This is why I have to multiplicate with 2.

Comment: Okay, so GetCountEdges doesn't return the weighted sum, but just the number of non-zero edges, correct?

Comment: I think your overall idea is good, but your implementation is just a bit broken. Try to debug each loop separately. For example, I think the only way to get x=0 is when randomNum=0, but clearly the chances of getting x=0 should be relative to the number of edges on vertex 0. I think you may have a collection of out-by-1 errors.

Comment: Well it returns the amount of edges that the graph has. This is a multigraph so I have to work like a weighted one but insteed of adding the weight in (x,y) I add the amount of the edges between this two vertex.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pick up a random integer k in `1:n*n-n` and choose the kth element if you order your valid pairs in an array, for instance columnwise : `[(v1,v2),(v1,v3),(v1,v4),(v2,v1),...]`.

If edges in this set are weighted, look at algorithm for random number generation that enables such weighting. SOme libraries are implementing such generators, as in http://randomlib.sourceforge.net/ in the RandomSelect class.

Comment: Yes, but in addition, you need to add weights into account, so you need to choose a random integer k from 1:(sum of all weights) and the list should repeat an edge according to its weight.

Comment: But if I have many edges this will get much work to create such a list. For example if I have over 2 million edges.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code seems reasonable, but it makes reasoning
about the uniform choice (with respect to edge weights difficult).

Consider the following graph.

```
   v1  v2  v3  v4
v1  0   1   1   1
v2  1   0   0   0
v3  1   0   0 999
v4  1   0 999   0

countEdges = 4
randomNum in [0, 7]

If randomNum < 3 then we see that 
   s = 0; x = 0; => we continue the loop
   s = 3; x = 1; => we exit the first loop
```

So now x never changes anywhere in the code, so the vertex
v2 must participate in the edge, at least 3/8 percent of the
time, which makes no sense since the edge weight is enormous
between v3 and v4.

### Alternative Solution 1

Use the Solution by @antitrust with my commentary. This is prohibitive if your graph is too large though.

### Alternative Solution 2

First get a total edge weight, so iterate over every entry and get the total sum of the matrix. This takes O(n) time (where n is the number of entries) and constant space.

```
int weight = Random.nextInt(totalWeight) + 1;
for(int i = 0; i < matrixSize; i++) {
    for(int j = i+1; j < matrixSize; j++) {
        if(weight <= Matrix[i][j]) {
            System.out.println("Row: " + i + " Col: " + j);
            return;
        }
        weight -= Matrix[i][j];    
    }
}
```

Clearly this runs over every entry in the matrix. You can make this faster if you are willing to trade time for space, by keeping cumulative row totals, so you can find the correct entry to choose from in O(MatrixSize + log(MatrixSize)) with a binary search variant in which you go through the row sums by binary search.

### Alternate Solution 3

You might want to consider using alternative data structures, (not an adjacency matrix), depending on how frequently you want to sample. Maybe Adjacency lists or some sort of maps might be better. Also Depends on how many 0's you have in your adjacency list.

Comment: I am trying your example but having problems that sometime doesnt print anything out. Going to debug that. But I already have an array of each vertex with the sum of the weight of his edges. So maybe it is possible to do the binary search variant. But I cant figure out how to implement this.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. Could you maybe explain me how to do that with the binary search variant? I have an array for each vertex which has the sum of the weights of every edge on this vertex. I cant find any information about how to find a random edge with the binary search.

Comment: With your example 2 I am having the problem that sometimes it doenst print anything out and sometimes it still finds an (x,x) edge.

Comment: Changed the index so we only consider the upper portion. Since adjacency matrix is symmetric.

Comment: Note that total weight in your case should be 6.

Comment: ok it seems that it now doesnt print the (x,x) edges but still sometimes it doenst print anything. which means that it ends without entering the if loop.

Comment: With my example matrix and lets get weight to 2. in the first round it will check in Matrix[0][1]. This is 1. So it will decrease weight to 1. now it will check Matrix[0][2]. This is 0. Nothing happens. Check Matrix[0][3]. This is 2. So it will decrease weight to -1. And because of that it doenst print any edge.

Comment: ok thank you. could you explain me how the binary search variant would work? I have the cumulative row totals but how can I find an random edge with the binary search?